# IPhone 5s ITunes Radio not supported

Tags: itunes

I try to listen to my iTunes Radio. And I'm currently on the latest iOS. And it says it's not supported. What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Do you fulfil these requirements?

**Apple Music Radio requirements**

To listen to Apple Music Radio, you need:

- iOS 8.4 or later on your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch. [Update](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204204) your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch.
- iTunes 12.2 or later on your Mac or PC. Get the [latest version](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201352).
- An [Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com/).

Apple Music Radio is available only in select countries. Find out [what's available in your country.](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204956)

Apple Music Radio features vary by country.

In some countries, an Apple Music membership is required to listen to Apple Music Radio.

Source: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204944